# Invalid dates parser

Tags: python, string, date, parsing

Is there an easy way to decrement an invalid date like "November 31st" to the last valid date of the month? November 31st does not exist as there aren't 31 days in November.

The date strings that I'm working with are very messy and inconsistent so I want to avoid trying to slice the string or anything like that. Parser.parse() works great for my use case when the dates aren't invalid.

```
from dateutil import parser

datstrings_list = ["Nov 31, 1976", "11/31/76", "11/31/1976", "November 31st, 1976","1/32/1976"]

date_list = []

for i in datestrings_list:

    datestring = i

    date = parser.parse(datestring).date()

    date_list.append(date)
```

Creates error:

```
ParserError: day is out of range for month: Nov 31, 1976
```

desired value for date_list:

```
[datetime.date(1976, 11, 30), datetime.date(1976, 11, 30),datetime.date(1976, 11, 30),datetime.date(1976, 11, 30), datetime.date(1/31/1976)]
```

Comment: curious, why do you have invalid dates though?

Comment: Messy data outside of my control -- the dates are provided outside the code process.

Comment: How "inconsistent" is the data? Regex might help: `re.findall(r"\d+", "Nov 31, 1976")` returns `['31', '1976']`.

Comment: Do it in try, catch the error, and then change the value and try parsing again?

Comment: The dates come in all sorts of different formats -- m/d/yy -- mm/dd/yyyy -- written out like in the code -- there may be a way to do numerous regexes within numerous try statements but I'm hoping there is a better solution out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of a `while` loop and complete it that way.

```
from dateutil import parser

datestring = "Nov 31, 1976"
date = None
while date is None:
    date_array = datestring.split()
    
    try:
        date = parser.parse(datestring).date()
    except parser._parser.ParserError:
        day = int("".join(x for x in date_array[1] if x.isdigit()))-1
        date_array[1] = f"{day},"
        datestring = f"{date_array[0]} {date_array[1]} {date_array[2]}"

print(date)
```

This should cover you for your needs.

UPDATE FOR QUESTION:

```
from dateutil import parser
import calendar

datestrings_list = ["Nov 31, 1976", "11/31/76", "11/31/1976", "November 31st, 1976","1/32/1976"]
c = {month: index for index, month in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr) if month}

# Format string list
def standardise_list(date_list):
    lst = []
    for index, ls in enumerate(date_list):
        if "/" not in ls:
            ds = ls.split()
            if len(ds[0]) > 3:
                ds[0] = ds[0][:3]

            if len(ds[1]) > 2:
                ds[1] = ds[1][:2]

            nd = f"{c[ds[0]]}/{ds[1]}/{ds[2]}"
            lst.append(nd)
        else:
            lst.append(ls)
    return lst

# Fix out of range dates
def date_fix(datestring):
    date = None
    while date is None:
        date_array = datestring.split("/")
        
        try:
            date = parser.parse(datestring).date()
        except parser._parser.ParserError:
            day = int("".join(x for x in date_array[1] if x.isdigit()))-1
            date_array[1] = f"{day}"
            datestring = f"{date_array[0]} {date_array[1]} {date_array[2]}"
    return date

standard_string_list = standardise_list(datestrings_list)

dates = [date_fix(ds) for ds in standard_string_list]
print(dates)

>>> [datetime.date(1976, 11, 30), datetime.date(1976, 11, 30), datetime.date(1976, 11, 30), datetime.date(1976, 11, 30), datetime.date(1976, 1, 31)]
```

Comment: sorry please see the update to my post -- I added a list to show all the date formats that the code needs to handle -- I'm not sure your solution would work with the update.

Comment: See modified solution which should work.

Comment: Cool thanks -- let me test this out and if it works I mark this as the answer.

Comment: Great it worked perfectly thank you!

Comment: Glad to here. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's an easy way to replace invalid dates with the max day for that month, but one approach could be to use helper functions under the `calendar` module to get the max day for a given month and year:

```py
import calendar

# Mapping of month abbreviation to month index. Ex: 'Jan': 1
month_indices = {month: i for i, month in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr)}

datestring = "Nov 31, 1976"

month_abbr, day, yr = datestring.replace(',', '').split()
last_day_in_month = calendar.monthrange(int(yr), month_indices[month_abbr])[-1]

assert last_day_in_month == 30
```

Alternatively, if you have a date string like `11/31/76`, here's how you get the max day for this month and year:

```py
datestring = "11/31/76"

month, day, year = map(int, datestring.split('/'))
# checking if we have abbreviation like `76` for year
# we have to make sure the year has 4 digits, otherwise `monthrange`
# appears to parse the year as `2076`, which is not what we want.
if year < 100:
    year += 1900

assert calendar.monthrange(year, month)[-1] == 30
```

Comment: Thanks for this -- could you take a look at my update though? I added a list that shows all the different formats the date could come in -- would your solution work in the updated case?

Comment: Nope, it would not work for other cases as is. I think the best option will be to use regex to parse out the month, day and year from a given string, and then check if the given day is valid for that month - though if you're sure most of the dates are valid, you could probably just try to parse them, and then catch the error and then change the day as above.

Comment: @DataofAllKinds I updated to show how you can handle a string like one of the other examples above. Though you probably will need to use regex or some kind of validation to determine the format of the string that you're receiving as an input.